# node.js variable for required module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out what it is that I don't know about javascript and/or node that when trying to use my `var fs = require('fs');` variable later on in my code. I have it working in another file the same way and other `require`d variables as well. Code below... Thanks!

EDIT: this is the error I get: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fs`

EDITEDIT: It might be worth noting that I do have and use `fs = require('fs')` in my `world.js` file which is also required in this file.

```
var keychain = require('keychain');
var world = require('./world').World;
var authentication = require('./authentication');
var fs = require('fs');

var getApps = function(appname, version, description){
  keychain.getPassword({ account: 'lightmanUsername', service: 'lightman' }, function(err,username) {
    keychain.getPassword({ account: 'lightmanPassword', service: 'lightman' }, function(err,password) {
      if (password === null) {
        console.log("Not logged in");
      } else {
        world(function(world) {

          authentication.authenticate(username,password);

          spooky.then(function(){
            this.capture('body.png', {
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: 1080,
              height: 800
            });
          });

          spooky.then(function(){
            var app = this.evaluate(function(){
              return $('.fwb').text();
            });
            console.log("APPS: " + app);
            this.download('https://developers.facebook.com/apps', 'app_list.html');
          });

          spooky.then(function(){
            var appList = fs.readFile('app_list.html');
            console.log(appList);
          });

          spooky.run();

        });
      }
    });
  });
};
exports.getApps = getApps;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use `fs` in your code?

Comment: just put it up in the edits, but its `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fs`

Comment: The error (almost certainly) isn't coming from that the file you show, instead it must be coming from a file you include and use. The error shown should include a stack trace, post that!

Comment: Besides what thomas stated, your fs.readFile code is incorrect.  fs.readFile is asynchronous and expects a callback.  I believe you wish to use the synchronous version, which would be fs.readFileSync('app_list.html')

Comment: When you execute code in phantomjs like that (I'm assuming spookyjs is the same) the code is being executed in the browser environment so I wouldn't expect the `fs` module to be available there.

Comment: thanks guys. it is definitely coming from this file because even when i change the variable name to something like `file = require('file')` and use that to make the call, it give me the same trace: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: file
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: file                                       
  /Users/Ohayon/EverTrue/falken:3
  /Users/Ohayon/EverTrue/falken:1326 in runStep
  /Users/Ohayon/EverTrue/falken:332 in checkStep
{ [Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 1] details: { code: 1, signal: null } }`

Comment: @NeonNinja that is the problem, youre right. but then I can't console.log it because it is not inside of a `spooky` command. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: got it. used this `var appList = file.readFileSync('app_list.html');
          spooky.then(function(appList){
            console.log(appList);
          });`

Comment: Well spotted @NeonNinja! One of you guys should write this up as an answer now so that others who find this question can learn from it.